# @click event not working in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've vue component and in it I wrote a function: when button is clicked `likes` get + 1 but it never works, I tried to write it inside component like this `@click="this.likes++' but not working, after that I created a method but it also not working. any help?

```js
Vue.component('task-list',{
  template: '<div><button @click="ggg">click me</button>{{ likes }}</div>',
  data(){
    return{
      likes:1
    }
  },
  methods:{
    ggg(){
      this.likes++
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are doing this properly? I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-violet-omxqs) using your code snippet and it works perfectly.